# How does one unit test modifying an XML document?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm at a loss for how to even begin creating unit tests for this method:

```
public override void ModifyXmlDocument(Foo foo, string nodeToChange, string newValue)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.Load(foo.XmlPathAndFileName);
    XmlElement rootElement = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
    // rest of method (to modify an XML doc) here
}
```

That method simply finds the element/node in an XML doc and updates it with the user-supplied value. (The method is more complex than what is shown here.)

The part that I'm having a hard time with is understanding how to have this method execute, without relying on the hard disk. But `xmlDocument.Load()` takes a file path and loads a file from disk. At the end of the method, it saves the updated file back to disk.

How can I make this method unit testable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this, but all require a refactoring of your code. `ModifyXmlDocument` will need to take `XmlDocument` as a parameter, then you can mock it from there on.

```
public void test_that_xml_is_loaded()
{
    var sut = new SUT();
    var xmldocumentfake = new Mock<XmlDocument>(){CallBase=true};
    xmldocumentfake.Setup(x=>x.LoadXml(It.IsAny<String>()));

    sut.ModifyXmlDocument(foo, nodeToChange, newValue, xmlDocumentfake.Object);

   xmldocumentfake.Verify(x=>x.LoadXml(It.IsAny<String>()), Times.Once());
}
```

You could also wrap the `XmlDocument` in another class that you can write as an abstraction that can be modified. Again, you would have to pass it in, though.

Also, as Anthony Pegram had alluded and what I mean: be careful that you are not breaking the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). When tests are too hard to write, that is often a scream that you have broken that principle.

Comment: +1 I like both options and I'll try them. Where did Anthony's answer go? I thought he made a good point.

Comment: He deleted it as it was pretty much exactly what I was saying. Once you have 10k+ points, then you can see deleted answers

Comment: Thanks. What mocking framework are you using in your example? It looks like Moq. I've used Moq, but not in the way (yet) that you've shown.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that. It is indeed Moq. This is a pretty basic example I thought.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options:

- If you are using VS2012 Ultimate, you can use the Fakes to create a shim that will override the behavior when XmlDocument opens the file.
- When you are testing, deploy a sample XML file with your unit tests.  Then when passing in a Foo instance, use the path to that file.
- Try one of the alternates to XmlDocument.Load such as one that takes a stream or XmlReader.  Then create that with a method that you can override.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the tips; I'll try #1. I thought about #2, but the file would be read only on disk and would fail on the save, and I wouldn't want it to save anyway.

Comment: Be careful of calling some of these unit tests. Especially option #2...when you hit other dependencies, then you are integration testing. No problem with that, but be aware of what you are writing and the speed costs and tradeoffs